# Visual Studio C++ "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing", disreagrding \MT & Static MFC linking

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015

I've been desperatly trying to get my School Project to run on those crappy school pcs, but i am not able to resolve the issue of missing Dll's.

My Project is set to "\MT" as Runtime Library and I've set MFC to static linking.
At first the MSVCP140.dll was missing, so i copied it in the folder with the .exe, but I'm not able to do that with before mentioned DLL.

Unfortunately, I can't install any runtimes or redists on the school pcs. (They run windows 7 with the latest updates)

**EDIT**:
I've did exactly what is recommended in all stackexachange answers, and it still doesn't work, so no, this is **no** duplicate.

Any help is appreciated! (it's my first stackoverflow question ^^)

Comment: Your options are 1) install the required DLLs on the target computer, or 2) statically link **all** dependencies into the executable. That's the two answers to the other question, and also the only options you have.

Comment: @BoPersson then maybe some explicit instructions for Visual Studio would be helpful? They make it easy to statically link MFC but I don't recall   seeing an option for the runtime.

Comment: Well the thing is that I already linked **everything** (even SDL, and i commented out every other dependency /library) statically and it still does not work. I literally did all tutorials or guides on that during the past 3 days. I hoped one of you guys have had this before.

Comment: @otto001 - And I have always used option 1 in cases like this - install what is required. I have no step-by-step guide for option 2 on Windows 7.